# Chile 2017, One of the Largest Fires in South America: Wood Ash Derivates for Industrial Applications

Tags: experimental-chemistry, concentration, safety, combustion, extraction

**Hi:** We're a group of people who wants to help people, domestic animals and wildlife recovering from this fire.

[image: A wood fire next to a road and next to some houses that were destroyed]

**Summary:**

- We're having in Chile one of the largest fires in South American history.
- More than 1,235,527 wood acres have already been burned
- The fires aren't stopped but rather increased
- People, domestic animals and wild fauna are suffering badly
- We're a group that wants to help in the recovery of the lands that have been burned
- There're several products with industrial applications that can be extracted from Wood Ashes. For instance, Potassium Peroxide
- Our idea is to do the following onsite:

  1. Build over a truck(s) a mobile laboratory
  2. Go to the places where there's too much ashes (making the soil extremely alkaline and hard to recover)
  3. Get some of the ashes, and extract a product with industrial application  that can be sold for a price that produce profitability
  4. The profits would be used for supporting the people who lost everything, helping the wildlife to recover faster and financing the project

The Question:

- Are there Wood Ash sub products that you think are suitable to be extracted on site and allow the mentioned objectives mentioned above?
- Do you know a technology to be used to do the extraction onsite?
- Do you know a chemist who could be interested to participate in the project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't the type of queries we expect on Chem.SE.

Comment: It may be better to do some consulting. Some universities have consulting organizations for physical sciences and mathematics. They may be better equipped to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm an economist and Berkeley MBA. I don't know Chemistry. Fortunately, some Chinese PhDs in Chemistry are already designing a solution! They will bring in the following days a team to help us.  ;)